# How to keep login status with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

#### Assumptions/what you want to achieve

Currently, I am learning about application development using Flutter+Firebase.

I want to implement the following functions as a part of the login function.

- Transition to the login page and login only when logging in for the first time
- Unless you log out, opening the app after exiting the app does not bring you to the login page

I did some research on my own and tried them, but they didn't work.
As a concrete method, how can the above functions be implemented?

Also, I am currently implementing a function that uses Firebase's Email and Password.

Is it a common method to implement the above functions even for Google login and Facebook login?

Since I am a new student of Flutter, I have many things that I do not understand, but I hope you can teach me.

#### Currently implemented

- Login function using Firebase Auth
- Database using Firebase Cloud Store

#### What I tried

- Check the login status using Current User of Firebase Auth

#### Additional information (FW/tool ​​version, etc.)

**Used**

- FirebaseAuth
- FirebaseCloudStore

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  final UserState user = UserState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserState>.value(
        value: user,
        child: MaterialApp(
          // Hide debug label
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title:'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: LoginCheck(),
          initialRoute: "/",
          routes:<String, WidgetBuilder>{
// "/": (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
            AddRecord.routeName: (BuildContext context) => AddRecord(),
            "/login":(BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
            "/home":(BuildContext context) => PageManager()
          },
        )
    );
  }
}

class LoginCheck extends StatefulWidget{
  LoginCheck({Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginCheckState createState() => _LoginCheckState();

}

class _LoginCheckState extends State<LoginCheck>{

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkUser();

    // TODO: implement initState


  }
  void checkUser() async{
    final UserState userState = Provider.of<UserState>(context);
    final currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print(currentUser);
    if(currentUser == null){
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,"/login");
    }else{
      userState.setUser(currentUser);
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text("Loading..."),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: go with https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Please ask your question in one sentence. And show the code you tried not the pubspec.

Comment: Firebase automatically persists the user's authentication state and restores it when the app restarts. Your `await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` should pick up the restored user. Which specific line in your code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your comment.
When I run the above code, it just displays the text "Loading...." and doesn't jump to the "login" or "home" page.
I'm not sure which part of the code is the cause, but I'm wondering if initState wasn't called

Comment: If you wonder about that, I'd recommend either setting a breakpoint in there and running in the debugger, or adding a `print` statement in there. Either of those can tell you if the code is being called.